# Check if file_get_contents url is working

Tags: php, json, ip, file-get-contents

I have a website, where I need to determine user's location, so I use webservice, which gives me detailed information about my user (using his IP address).

My function looks like this:

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$json_url = 'http://example.com/'.$user_ip;
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Today morning this webservice had a problems (500 errors, too many connections, bad gateway...) and my website was loading very long time.

So I have a question: Is it possible to set timeout for file_get_contens function? Or maybe there are a ways to get fast that the server is not working?

Comment: I think you should use curl instead of file_get_contents()

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `timeout` option of the `http` context:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'timeout' => 5
    )
);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($opts));
```

Check the docs of:

- [stream_context_create()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)
- [HTTP context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)

---

An alternative would be to set the default socket timeout via `ini_set()`:

```
$st = ini_get("default_socket_timeout"); // backup current value
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 5000); // 5 seconds

$content = file_get_contents($url);
if($content === false) {
    // error handling
}

ini_set("default_socket_timeout", $st); // restore previous value
```